# angular 2 web worker Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: angularjs, import, web-worker

I am trying to use a webworker in angular 2. The web worker should use the THREE JS library in the following folder:

> ../Angular2-App-Boilerplate/node_modules/three/src/Three.js

my angular 2 app is located here:

> ../Angular2-App-Boilerplate/src/app

in my component I using the THREE JS library:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

and I am creating the web worker like this:

```
let worker = new Worker('src/app/threed-viewer/threed-model-loader.worker.ts');
      let message = 'assets/data/GuyFawkesMask.ply';

      worker.postMessage(message);
```

in the worker file

> ../Angular2-App-Boilerplate/src/app/threed-viewer/threed-model-loader.worker.ts

everything works fine if I keep things simple but as soon as I am importing the THREE JS library using the same line I use in my component:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Any idea? Thank you,

Dino

Comment: i don't think you can import a `.ts` file. You can try with compiled `.js`